# How to fix source-code generator with .NET 6?

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, csharp-source-generator

I ported my .NET 5.0 application to .NET 6.0 and now I found that the source-code generator fails. It shows the following error:

> Generator 'PermissionGenerator' failed to generate source. It will not contribute to the output and compilation errors may occur as a result. Exception was of type 'FileNotFoundException' with message 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Collections.Immutable, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'

Adding `<CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>` to the property-group of the generator's project-file didn't really help. It does add `System.Collection.Immutable.dll` to the output folder (6.0.21.52210), but I still get the same error.

My generator is a .NET Standard 2.0 project, which might not be necessary anymore with .NET 6. So I also tried setting the runtime for the generator to .NET 6. This failed with another error:

> An instance of analyzer ... cannot be created from ... Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this is an issue with Paket v6 that seems to have a problem when used in conjunction with source-generators. I now use the traditional approach (including the analyzers directly in the project-file) and it now works again. I filed an issue with Paket ([link](https://github.com/fsprojects/Paket/issues/4097)).

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue in my project by downgrading `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp` to version `4.0.1`. I guess newer versions have an issue finding `System.Collections.Immutable`.

This is with my source generator on `netStandard2.0` and the project the source was being generated for on `net6.0`.